# javascript remove all elements :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

This type of questions has been asked alot in this site, but i don't understand why this happens.
I want to write a script that removes all elements with class "not_imp_msg" and i did this

```
setTimeout($('.not_imp_msg').each(function(){$(this).slideDown();}),2000);
```

Actually this is for flash message in laravel and in my flash.blade.php

```
@foreach($flash as $flash_message)
    @if(isset($flash_message['status']) && $flash_message['status'] != null)
<div class="box box-{{$flash_message['class']}} box-solid">
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
      {{$flash_message['message']}}
    </div>
  </div>
    @else
    <div class="box box-{{$flash_message['class']}} box-solid not_imp_msg">
      <div class="box-body">
      {{$flash_message['message']}}
    </div>
  </div>
    @endif

@endforeach
```

This gives me the error after 2 seconds but all elements slides up as soon as documents load. Should it not wait for 2 seconds. I can't understand why.

Comment: You need to wrap timeout callback in anonymous function: `setTimeout(function(){...}, 2000);`

Comment: sorry? can u please explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing anonymous function, as `setTimeout` is expecting function name or anonymous function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.not_imp_msg').slideDown();
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.not_imp_msg {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="not_imp_msg"></div>
<div class="not_imp_msg"></div>
<div class="not_imp_msg"></div>
<div class="not_imp_msg"></div>
<div class="not_imp_msg"></div>
```

---

*Side notes*

If you want to remove elements, than use callback function of `slideUp(callback)` to `.remove` elements.

---

`.slideDown` will reveal elements, `.slideUp` will collapse elements, but they will still be presented in DOM with 0px height

Comment: I forgot to call closure on setTimeout. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
setTimeout(
function () {
    $('.not_imp_msg').each(function(){
       $(this).slideDown();
    };
}, 2000);
```

Hope it work!
By the way, can you provide the error message in console?

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to wrap the inside of your setTimeout in a function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.not_imp_msg').each(function(){$(this).slideDown();}) 
},2000);
```